# I need to prove that a sequence converges

Tags: calculus

Let $a_n,b_n>0$ and let $\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n}=L>0$ and $b_n$ be bounded.

Also: $b_{n+1} \geq \frac{b_{n} a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

I need to prove that $b_n$ is a convergent sequence.

Comment: @coffeemath From the comment template in MathMeta.SE, one sees that one has to type the math using MathJax instead of posting photos.  Therefore, "this" should not even exist.

Comment: The ratio of $a_n$ go to 1. So $b_n$ i increasing, so it converge at his upper bound.

Comment: @G.Cantisani That's not right. Take $a_n = 1 + 1/n$ and $b_n = a_n.$

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n>0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n}=L>0$, $a_n$ is bounded from below by a positive constant, meaning $\displaystyle\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ is bounded. But $\displaystyle b_{n+1} \geq \frac{b_{n} a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is equivalent with $\displaystyle\frac{b_{n+1}} {a_{n+1}}\ge\frac{b_n}{a_n}$, i.e. $\displaystyle\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ is monotone increasing and bounded and thus convergent. Then, $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{b_n}{a_n}\,a_n$ is convergent, too.